# Searching user by sub return InvalidParameterException

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-java-sdk

I need to retrieve a user in cognito from a java lambda function using the sub attribute of the user-pool.

According to the documentation, the listUsers method lets you search for the sub and returns a list of UserType: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_ListUsers.html

Quotation marks within the filter string must be escaped using the backslash \

this is the call that I built:

```
public UserType getUserBySub(String sub) {
        String filter = "\" sub = \\\""+sub+"\\\"\"";
        ListUsersRequest listUsersRequest = new ListUsersRequest()
                .withUserPoolId("us-east-1_xxxxxxx")
                .withAttributesToGet("name", "email")
                .withFilter(filter);
        ListUsersResult listUsersResult =  AWSCognitoIdentityProviderClientBuilder.defaultClient()
                .listUsers(listUsersRequest);
        UserType user = listUsersResult.getUsers().get(0);
        return user;
    }
```

and I received the error:

```
Error while parsing filter. (Service: AWSCognitoIdentityProvider; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterException; Request ID: 9038d937-eedf-491c-a3bd-51dc1da5eb99): com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidp.model.InvalidParameterException
com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidp.model.InvalidParameterException: Error while parsing filter. (Service: AWSCognitoIdentityProvider; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterException; Request ID: 9038d937-eedf-491c-a3bd-51dc1da5eb99)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1712)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1367)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1113)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:770)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:744)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:726)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:686)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:668)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:532)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:512)
at com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidp.AWSCognitoIdentityProviderClient.doInvoke(AWSCognitoIdentityProviderClient.java:7761)
at com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidp.AWSCognitoIdentityProviderClient.invoke(AWSCognitoIdentityProviderClient.java:7728)
at com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidp.AWSCognitoIdentityProviderClient.invoke(AWSCognitoIdentityProviderClient.java:7717)
at com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidp.AWSCognitoIdentityProviderClient.executeListUsers(AWSCognitoIdentityProviderClient.java:5861)
at com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidp.AWSCognitoIdentityProviderClient.listUsers(AWSCognitoIdentityProviderClient.java:5832)
```

To take the test, I made request using CLI and works as expected:

```
aws cognito-idp list-users --user-pool-id us-east-1_xxxxxx --filter "sub = \"3c02267b-3786-478f-a760-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\""
```

Did I make a mistake in the code? Or sounds like a bug in the java SDK?

Comment: I don't know that api but escaping the double quotes on the cli is needed to get them into the filter string which then should look like `sub = "whatever"`. The string you're building in your Java code looks like `" sub = \"whatever\""` (that's the _value_ not the literal). Try `String filter = "sub = \""+sub+"\"";` instead.

Comment: @Thomas same error

Answer (score 0):

From the sdk you do not need to escape the values. Using

```
String filter = "sub = \"" + sub + "\"";
```

should work. If sub can contain " you need to escape those

```
String filter = "sub = \"" + sub.replaceAll("\"", "\\\"") + "\"";;
```